# Issue with shuffling an array of strings per 1 day in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to shuffle an array of strings per day but I am encountering errors. One error is highlighted saying “ Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range'” and another error is highlighted saying “ Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Int.Words' conform to 'StringProtocol'”. I’m not sure what I am doing wrong. Please review my code below…

```
struct TestView: View {
var words: [String] = [
    "Hello", "Hola", "Ciao",
]
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ForEach(isNewDay() ? words.shuffled() : words) { word in //Error: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
            Text(word.words) //Error: Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Int.Words' conform to 'StringProtocol'
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .padding(.top, 1)
        }
    }
}
func isNewDay()-> Bool{
    
    let currentDate = Date()
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    
    let currentDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    
    if let lastSaved  = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastDate"){// last saved date
        
        
        if lastSaved == currentDateString{
            return true
        }else{
            
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(currentDateString, forKey: "lastDate")
            return false
            
        }
    }else{
        
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(currentDateString, forKey: "lastDate")
        return false
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ForEach(isNewDay() ? words.shuffled() : words, id: \.self) { word in  // <-- here
                Text(word) // <-- here
```